# Riesz transform on almost periodic functions?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, almost-periodic-function

It is well established that the Riesz transform is well-defined for $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ via$$
\mathcal{R}_jf(x) = c_d\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int_{|x-y|>\epsilon}\frac{(x^j-y^j)f(y)}{|x-y|^{d+1}}\,dy
$$
and in particular it is bounded as a singular integral operator $L^p\to L^p$. I came across this problem of discussing the behavior of almost periodic functions (denoted by $CAP$) under Riesz transform. At first glance it seems to me that in this case $\mathcal{R}_jf$ might not even be well-defined, as $CAP\subset L^{\infty}$ and the above singular integral diverges. I am just curious whether the almost periodicity would make the story a little different, as in the case of periodic functions. If not, are there any additional properties one can add to make it work? Thanks in advance.